# Window control buttons appearing on the status bar

Tags: window-manager, window-buttons, statusbar

I have the icons appear in the status bar. They appear even when there is no window open and do nothing when clicked.

It started happening after upgrading to 20.04.

[image]

How can I remove these icons?

Comment: Looks like this is an extension-provided feature. Open the `extensions` app and keep disabling the extensions to find out the culprit.

Comment: Thanks, FYI for xomeone reading this in the future, I had to install the extensions app first: `sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-prefs`